# How to upload JaCoCo reports to SonarQube in a separate call after the successful analysis?

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

In my company we are running some legacy application which takes too long to compile and post that we are using sonar to scan the code, so in total the job takes around 3 hrs approx through teamcity in single build configuration

Hence i come up with the idea of static analysis in separate configuration which will scan the code parallely while the other job does the compilation part, By doing this way i was able to save some good amount of time but the jacoco reports are getting generated during the build compilation part and i want to inject the jacoco.exec report directly into the sonar dashboard since the sonar execution is separate.

Will there be any way to achive this like curl rest api to upload the jacoco report in the sonar dashboard of particular project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to push JaCoCO reports separately. All analysis data must go together.

> Hence i come up with the idea of static analysis in separate configuration which will scan the code parallely while the other job does the compilation part

Don't do this. SonarScanner uses binary data and tests results to perform analysis. If your application will be not compiled then:

- the scanner will find less issues due to missing data
- the analysis will fail (again, due to missing data)

If the process is too long, I would recommended to execute SonarScanner less frequently (for example once a day for main branches).

Comment: Accept the answer, please :)

Comment: Just opened this topic: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/independent-command-to-push-jacoco-report-after-analysis/24144